# Can I use connect-mongo without Mongoose?

Tags: mongoose, connect-mongo

I'd prefer to use another ORM or just the core MongoDb driver.  How hard would it be to make this possible?  I'm currently using Monk, which is a light wrapper on top of Mongoskin.

Answer (score 1):

`connect-mongo` doesn't rely on Mongoose at all. If you use it in its default setting, it will use the native MongoDB driver to create a database connection for itself (see [here](https://github.com/jdesboeufs/connect-mongo#express-or-connect-integration)):

```
const session    = require('express-session');
const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);

app.use(session({
    secret : 'foo',
    store  : new MongoStore(options)
}));
```

There's also a specific MongoSkin store: [`connect-mongoskin`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-mongoskin).